# ORB/BruteForce-drawing matches when there are none

Tags: c++, opencv, brute-force, orb

I'm trying to write a program that uses ORB algorithm to detect and compute the keypoints of an image and a video and matches descriptor vectors using BruteForce matcher. The issue I am facing is, that every time I run the program on Visual C++, when the object that I'm trying to detect is not visible, my algorithm is drawing all the supposed matching lines between the keypoints detected(it matches all the keypoints). When the object that I'm trying to detect appears in the image I don't face this issue, in fact, I hardly get any mismatches.

This is a brief sequence of the main test:

• convert input image to grayscale

• convert input videos to grayscale

• detect keypoints and extract descriptors from input grayscale image

• detect keypoints and extract descriptors from input grayscale videos

• match descriptors(see below)

```
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING);
    vector<DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    ////calcularea distantelor max si min distances intre keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);


    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance <= max(2 * min_dist, 0.02))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    ////-- Desenarea matches-urilor "bune"
    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img1, keypoints_1, cadruProcesat, keypoints_2,
        good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
        vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    ////-- Afisare matches
    imshow("good matches", img_matches);
    int gm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i, good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx);
        gm += 1;
    }

    printf("%d",gm);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //imshow(windowName2, cadruProcesat);

    switch (waitKey(10)) {

    case 27:
        //tasta 'esc' a fost apasata(ASCII 27) 
        return 0;
    }
}

return 0;
```

Please help me find the problem.

Comment: Either, `you are not checking when your Keypoints_2 is empty` or the problem is somewhere else. Get us the `matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);` for a better help.

Answer (score 0):

So I've changed the value of min_dist to 15(not 100) and it seems that it works very well for patterns... but this was done by trial and error...